# Calculation with Large numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{fp}


\begin{document}

\tikzmath{
real \x; int \i; real \s;
    \s = 0;
    for \i in {1,2,...,15}{
        \s = \s + 2^\i; 
        \x{\i} = \s;
    };
}

\vspace{3cm}

\foreach \i in {1,2,...,15}{
O valor da soma \i~ é desta sequência é \x{\i} \\ 
}

\end{document}
```

Why `tikzmath` does not perform the calculations above of 2^14? How can I overcome this please? Any package, library to do calculation with bigger numbers?

Comment: looks like same question as [tikz pgf - Dimension too large - Tikzmath - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623928/dimension-too-large-tikzmath) or [tikz pgf - \pgfmathsetmacro - dimension too large (biggest value allowed?) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54702/pgfmathsetmacro-dimension-too-large-biggest-value-allowed?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

The [sagetex package](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex) gives you access to the Python programming language and a computer algebra system known as [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/tour.html). This lets you handle most any problem easily. Search this site for other examples.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
output = r""
sum = 0
for i in range(1,37):
  sum += 2^i
  output += r"\noindent O valor da soma $%d$ é desta sequência é $%d$\\"%(i,sum)
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{output}
\end{document}
```

The output running in [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) is:
[image]

The %d is for integer data, %f is for float and %s for string data.

Sage is not part of the LaTeX distribution. It can be downloaded onto your computer but the simplest way to get started is a free Cocalc account.

Comment: Alternatives for Python in TeX: [Embedding Python in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238016/embedding-python-in-latex)